# Use SLF4J with GlassFish 6.2.2 server on JDK11

Tags: glassfish, slf4j, java-11

I just tried to get GlassFish 6.2.2 server on JDK11 to work with [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/). With GlassFish versions <=6.0.0 on JDK 8 I always used the [instructions](http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2010/12/glassfish-logging-with-slf4j-part-2.html) by Harald Wellmann to install SLF4J.

One step from the instructions is to copy SLF4J and logback libraries to the `<glassfish-directory>/lib/endorsed` directory.

But JDK11 seems to not support endoresed libraries anymore. Even if I copy the files to `<glassfish-directory>/lib` or `<glassfish-directory>/domains/domain1/lib`, they are not found.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
```

Harald Wellmann wrote on his blog that

> the bridge has to be visible to the classloader evaluating the logging configuration. Since Glassfish starts logging very early in its bootstrapping phase, the lib/endorsed folder is the only place where the bridge has the desired effect.

Is there another way to use slf4j with GlassFish server on JDK 11?

Comment: According to David Matějček this approach is not working anymore because of the missing endorsed functionality (https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/24138#issuecomment-1287108793).